# Make Title Bar Blink faster with Jquery Plugin, Interval is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this jquery plugin from https://github.com/heyman/jquery-titlealert

Can you help me set the speed for the title message to blink faster in Chrome? I tried lessening the interval but it did not blink too fast enough. It seems to work fine in Mozilla though.

```
<script>
    $.titleAlert(".", {
    requireBlur:false,
    stopOnFocus:false,
    duration:3000,
    interval:30,
});
</script>
```

I appreciate your help on this one!
Sorry guys I'm a newb here :)

Comment: see here :http://heyman.info/2010/sep/30/jquery-title-alert/#documentation

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried lowering the interval already. The speed that I want is only showing on Mozilla and it is slower in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following coding snippet

```
setInterval(function(){
    var title = document.title;
    document.title = (title == "test" ? "none" : "test");
}, 1000);
```

Use `document.title = ...`

You are just editing an attribute which does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the help,really appreciate it! How to you make it stop? I just need the title to blink for at least 3-5seconds then stop.. @viral-shah

Comment: You can study this, you can find the play around.
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/